# Trouble with LibreOffice index and styles

Tags: styles, libreoffice-writer

I have a problem with creating an index to a document: it was not created from me, and it had the headers of the chapters as normal text, without using styles. I applied styles (Header 1, 2, 3 and Body) to the whole document, hoping that it would allow to create the index automatically.

But when I insert the index, it appears empty.

I tried to create a dummy document to try the function and it works properly; so what could be wrong in the other document?

Comment: Hi, did you use built in header styles or custom ones? If you use custom header styles, you have to set the index to also use custom styles and then define, which style is which index level. Look in the index settings, I cannot give you the exact dialog name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem.

It was caused by the fact that in the settings of the style used as header, it was not set for appearing in the index. More in detail, I had to go in the "HeadingX" setting (for the styles I've used), and then in the "Outline&Numbering" tab; there, I had to choose in the "Outline level" drop-down menu, the level in which I want the index entry to appear.

I hope that this could help someone else.